# What's the difference between PuTTY and SSH?

Tags: ssh, putty

Also, what is the difference between pscp, psftp and scp, sftp?

I'm guessing PuTTY is originally made for Windows which doesn't have these commands by default, am I right?

If that's the case, why would anyone use PuTTY on Linux?

Comment: `scp` and `sftp` are confusing, because they are both protocols (ie, many programs can use them) *and* the name of the program/utility in Linux/Unix

Comment: Whereas the `pscp` program in the PuTTY suite implements almost the commandline arguments of `scp` but can use either protocol, while the `psftp` program implements the more complicated and flexible interface _and_ protocol of `sftp`.

Comment: One good reason to have PuTTY ported to GNU/Linux is that it can be run under Valgrind to find bugs, fixing which could benefit the Windows version.

Comment: Update, since this was necroed already: [in OpenSSH since 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) the `scp` _program_ uses the SFTP protocol by default.

Answer (score 13):

PuTTY is a *terminal emulator* (able to run shells, which in turn run commands), while the usual SSH application is a shell (not a terminal emulator).  PuTTY has been ported to Unix (and Unix-like) systems as **[`pterm`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/pterm/pterm.1.en.html)** (a [Debian package](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/p/putty/putty_0.78-2_changelog) since 2002).

`scp` is a special case: a program use for copying a few files via an `ssh` connection.  PuTTY on Windows has a similar program, but there's no need for that in the Unix port.

`sftp` (and `psftp`...) would be analogous to **`ftp`**: specialized programs used for copying many files.

Their usefulness depends on what you need to do: some use `scp` far more often than `sftp`, and vice versa.

Comment: When I search online for `pterm` it says it's something for Go.

Answer (score 9):

- **[SSH](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/secsh/documents/)** is a protocol for encrypted connections between computers. It is quite flexible as it allows multiple streams in one connection (e.g. terminal sessions, file transfers and TCP port forwardings).
- **[SCP](https://web.archive.org/web/20170215184048/https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works)** is a simple protocol for file transfers via SSH connections.
- **[SFTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-moonesamy-secsh-filexfer-00)** is a protocol to transfer files, list directories, etc. via SSH connections.
- **PuTTY** is a GUI *terminal emulator* for Windows with a built-in SSH client for remote terminal sessions.
- **`ssh`** is a command line SSH client. There is a port for Windows named *OpenSSH for Windows*.
- **`scp`** is a specialized program to copy files via SCP. `pscp` is a port from the PuTTY suite with the same purpose.
- **`sftp`** is an interactive command line program to manage files via SFTP. It allows copying, deleting and listing of files similarly to the command line tool `ftp`. `psftp` is again a port from the PuTTY suite with the same purpose.

PuTTY combines multiple features (customizable terminal emulation, remote connection, serial port access, etc.) that are usually separated on Linux/Unix because Windows by default only includes a limited "terminal emulator", the command prompt window. Another reason was, as you suspected, that Windows doesn't have `ssh` by default.

There are multiple terminal emulators on Linux that work well with `ssh`, so there is no real need for PuTTY on Linux.
The main reasons to use PuTTY on Linux would be its session management, the customization features that help talking to machines with bugs and/or unusual terminal settings (character set, key bindings, etc.) and the feature to also access serial ports.

Comment: You probably meant that `scp` transfers files via SSH not SCP.

Comment: No.  `scp` transfers files with the SCP protocol which uses SSH.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected!

Comment: Probably just a matter of being out-of-date, but Windows 10 + 11 support `ssh` from PS and CMD for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple

```
putty - A software used to connect servers with protocol's like ssh ftp
```

.

```
ssh - A protocol used to connect the server through port 22.
```

Comment: Not really; PuTTY can natively do SSH Rblah TELNET and anything you can manage to hand-type over a 'raw' TCP connection, but not FTP because it uses _multiple_ TCP connections; SSH can be and often is used over ports other than 22, and many other protocols are used to connect to many many and various servers.